# Get only one word from a dictonary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, output

```
import COVID19Py

covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19()
latest = covid19.getLatest()
print(latest)
```

This is my code an the output is:

```
{'confirmed': 106160999, 'deaths': 2317170, 'recovered': 12778299}
```

But i want that the output is something like:

```
"There are 106160999 infections and 2317170 deaths and 12778299 recovers"
```

Comment: Questions as basic as this indicate that you might find it more helpful to follow some tutorials on dictionaries and formatting strings in Python. There are many such tutorials on the web, and Stack Overflow is not one of them. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: How is your desired result just getting one word from the dictionary? It looks like you want all the words, just formatted in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [27]: latest = {'confirmed': 106160999, 'deaths': 2317170, 'recovered': 12778299}                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [28]: print(f"There are {latest['confirmed']} infections and {latest['deaths']} deaths and {latest['recovered']} recovers")                                                                                                                                                
There are 106160999 infections and 2317170 deaths and 12778299 recovers
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to access the dictionary, you can write:

```
print(f"There are {your_dict["confirmed"]} infections and ....")
```

You can access a dictionary with the key like an array